# Regex.Replace and static context?

Tags: c#, static-methods

I have this code here:

```
private Func<string, string> RemoveSpecialChars = str => Regex.Replace(str, "[ ./\\-]");
```

Its complaining (*Can not access non-static method Replace in static context*) about the call to Replace, because of static context. Whats wrong?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 20):

You need to use the method `Regex.Replace(input,pattern,replacement)`, [the one you use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx) is not static :

```
private Func<string, string> RemoveSpecialChars = 
                       str => Regex.Replace(str, "[ ./\\-]", replacementString);
```

Answer (score 7):

The static overload of [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx) has a different signature:

```
public static string Replace(
    string input,
    string pattern,
    string replacement
)
```

You're missing the `replacement` parameter

Comment: Ahhhh...didnt see the wood for the trees :D